# ST_DWithin takes parameter as degree , not meters , why?

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, srid

The [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_DWithin.html) document says , the third parameter(distance) is in meters. But when I execute some query , it seems it takes the 3rd parameter as 'degree' ?

Here is my simplified table structure :

```
> \d+ theuser;
                         Table "public.theuser"
  Column  |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Description 
----------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 id       | bigint                 | not null  | plain    | 
 point    | geometry               |           | main     | 
Indexes:
    "theuser_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "point_index" gist (point)
Referenced by:
    ...
Has OIDs: no
```

All points are stored with SRID=4326.

And this is the query :

```
> select * from theuser where ST_DWithin(point , ST_GeomFromText('POINT(120.9982 24.788)',4326) , 100 );
```

It takes the 3rd parameter (100) as 'degree' , so it returns all data , I have to narrow down to 0.001 to find nearby points.

But how do I directly pass meters as 3rd parameter (I don't want to do meter/degree transformation ) ? What's wrong with my query ? why postgreSQL doesn't take it as meters as document says ?

Environments :

```
> select version();
                                                  version                                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 8.4.9 on i486-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc-4.4.real (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3, 32-bit

> SELECT postgis_lib_version();
 postgis_lib_version 
---------------------
 1.4.0
```

If it is the SRID that causes this problem , what SRID directly makes use of 'meter' as the unit ? (I tried transforming to SRID=2163 , but still in degree) Thanks.

Comment: Could you specify how exactly you transformed your data to SRID=2163?

Comment: Hi , I am not familiar with postgis . So I programmatically reset each point with a new SRID value

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_DWithin.html):

> For Geometries: The distance is specified in units defined by the
> spatial reference system of the geometries.

If your data is in SRID=4326 the distance you are specifying is in degrees.

You either have to use [ST_Transform](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Transform.html) and meter based coordinate system, or one of the two functions: [ST_Distance_Sphere](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) (faster, less accurate) or [ST_Distance_Spheroid](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html).

Comment: Yes , I also thought it maybe the SRID's reason. But what SRID default uses meters ?

Comment: Have a look at first two chapters of [Understanding Map Projections](http://kartoweb.itc.nl/geometrics/Map%20projections/Understanding%20Map%20Projections.pdf) to get familiar with the difference between geographic and projected coordinate systems. Choosing projected coordinte sytem depends on several factors, mainly geographic region of your data, and what you plan to measure with it. See also Choosing coordinate systems](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2769/choosing-coordinate-systems) on GIS SE.

Comment: +1 Isn't there a third alternative though? Just pass the distance in radians (fastest of all, if it is acceptable)

Comment: Per https://nsidc.org/data/atlas/epsg_4326.html and http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/, the base units for EPSG 4326 are degrees, not radians.

Comment: The first option "meter based coordinate system" needs to specify a meter based coordinate system. Can you suggest one what can be used globally, so distance_sphere works properly? Better solution is one suggested by @sal - convert objects to geography, and then use proper spherical distance within ST_DWithin. Note that ST_DWithin is also faster than  ST_Distance_Sphere: http://postgis.net/2013/08/26/tip_ST_DWithin/

Answer (score 15):

If your `geometry` is in WGS84, i.e. srid 4326, you can cast the geometries to `geography` to have the units in meters

```
SELECT *
FROM theuser
WHERE ST_DWithin(
  point::geography,
  ST_GeomFromText('POINT(120.9982 24.788)',4326)::geography,
  100 -- DISTANCE IN METERS
);
```

Answer (score 4):

As it referenced here, https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html, there are two different signatures for ST_DWithin function.

If anyone wants to use meters directly, the second signature which has a boolean flag will work.

As a JPA example, I'm posting my query below.

```
    @Query("select f from Facility as f where dwithin(f.address.coordinates, :center, 10000, true) = TRUE")
    List<Facility> findAllByDistance(@Param("center") Point point);
```

Comment: This works like a charm, I'm surprised it wasn't the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

I would't recommend you to transform to meters every time you want to use DWithin, by the way if you want meters you need an equal area projection like [Albers projection](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3005/) (there are many), why dont you try ST_Buffer(point, degrees) , and see what it does on google earth, make measures and find a number that you like, normally you need predefined ranges, something like very near = 0.00008, near = 0.0005, far = 0.001, really far = 0.01, really really far= 0.1, etc. (all in degrees).

In a previous question you asked for the fastest way, you are in the right direction.

Answer (score -3):

Try below query, its working fine for me.

```
select * from theuser where ST_DWithin(point , ST_GeomFromText('POINT(120.9982 24.788)',4326) , 0.1/111.325 );
```

Here, 0.1 = 100 meters.