# PostGIS ST_DWithin distance_of_srid Using Degrees, When Should Be Meters

Tags: postgis

I have run into a problem using PostGIS ST_DWithin using geometry points that has me completely stumped.  Even though I'm using geometry points with SRID 3857 (see below), ST_DWithin interprets seems to interpret the third argument ( double precision distance_of_srid ) as DEGREES.  Here's an example.

Using this table test_person_avg_lngs_lats:

```
       Column        |         Type         | Modifiers 
---------------------+----------------------+-----------
 avg_lng             | double precision     | 
 avg_lat             | double precision     | 
 person_avg_location | geometry(Point,3857) | 
 store_lng           | double precision     | 
 store_lat           | double precision     | 
 store_location      | geometry(Point,3857) |
```

and the following query:

```
SELECT avg_lat, avg_lng, store_lng, store_lat,
    ST_Distance_Spheroid(person_avg_location, store_location, CAST('SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG","7030\"]]' AS spheroid))/1000 AS distance,
    ST_DWithin(person_avg_location, store_location, 1) AS dwithin
FROM test_person_avg_lngs_lats
WHERE ST_DWithin(person_avg_location, store_location, 1)
```

The query returns results that interpret the third argument to ST_DWithin as 1 DEGREE versus 1 METER, even though I'm using geometry points with SRID 3857 which I have confirmed, uses meters units.  Whatever N I pass as the third argument to ST_DWithin, the results consistently return distances around N * 100 km ( ~ 66 miles ).  That's why I'm assuming ST_DWithin is interpreting it as 1 DEGREE.

Here is a sample result that should be interpreted as one meter (distance is in miles):

```
avg_lat         avg_lng        store_lng  store_lat  distance       dwithin
43.3275959623, -71.1169553872, -71.0626,  42.3291,   68.9794023576, true
```

This is the closest I've come to something on the subject: [ST_DWithin takes parameter as degree , not meters , why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444753/st-dwithin-takes-parameter-as-degree-not-meters-why)

Any ideas as to what might be causing this, or what I might look for to move forward in analyzing the problem?

I'm using:

```
postgis_full_version                                                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="2.0.0 r9605" GEOS="3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER
(1 row)

version                                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.1.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Comment: Perhaps the distance_of_srid 3857 is in fact degrees, and not meters?  How to confirm? \n INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( +units=m +no_defs ', 'PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo- [SNIPS] Mercator",Sphere",6378137,0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7059"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6055"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4055"]],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, `distance_of_srid` uses the same distance units of the SRID, which is typically either degrees or meters. With the `geometry` type, distances are calculated on a flat Cartesian plane [using maths familiar to most high school students](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). The units are *not* interpreted for the `geometry` type.

However, this assumes that the data are actually projected with the correct SRID. If you mix a projected SRID like 3857 with lat/long coordinates expressed as degrees than you will get unexplainable garbage. Review how you populated the `person_avg_location` and `store_location` columns, because I'm 99.9% certain that there was an error there.